# Show thumbnail in flutter Image.network widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I tried to use Image.network() flutter widget to view a thumbnail image from youtube video which was added manually but the image in the widget displays with top and bottom.black screen but not a full one based on the container width and height as below image[image]

What could be a problem?

```
Stack (
children:[
   Container (
       child: Image.network (
               Url,
              fit:BoxFit.cover,
                height: 500,
                widht: 400

          ),
   Container (
 aligment:Alignment.bottonLeft,
    child: Text (
       Name
        )
     )
    )
   ]
);
```

Comment: please post the code

Comment: I have already edit the post

Comment: why you have added height: 500, widht: 400

Comment: I tried to make it fit but got the same result..

Comment: Also when i took a thumbnail udeo link to diplay it into chrome browser the same result appear ..i domt kow why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fit` property.

```
Image.network(fit:BoxFit.cover, src: 'image path')
```

Comment: Without any property?